# linq to entities decimal null values from outer join

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

LINQ giving an error while using the below linq

```
var data = (from p in _context.Products
                    from invp in _context.Inventories
                    .Where(inv=>inv.Product.ID== p.ID)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()//left outer join
                   select new { p.ID, p.Name, p.BarCode, p.ProductCategory,  p.MRP, p.RetailPrice,stock=invp.Stock } ).ToList()  ;
```

The cast to value type `System.Decimal` failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

If I remove invp.stock from the select it is working , how can I default invp.stock to 0 if it is null.

Answer (score 0):

You may select like this:
replace

```
stock=invp.Stock
```

with

```
stock=invp.Stock ?? 0
```

Comment: Thanks..But it is giving compiler error Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'int'

Comment: Oh sorry this may not be accepted in current MVC 4.

Comment: I thought `case when` would be better solution in SQL for this case but as you are using LINQ. It might be little bit difficult.

Comment: It worked with a nullable decimal casting Stock = (decimal?)invp.Stock

Answer (score 0):

There is nullable decimal and we need to cast them then  only it can take the database null to c#

Stock = (decimal?)invp.Stock